# How do I get the Podio app item name found in App Settings?

Tags: c#, podio

How can I get the App Item name in this picture in C#?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Podio API](https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-area-22349)?

**Applications: Get app**

```
GET /app/{app_id}
```

Gets the definition of an app and can include configuration and fields. This method will always return the latest revision of the app definition.

The result (micro result):

```
{
  "app_id": The id of the app,
  "name": The name of the app,
  "item_name": The name of each item in an app,
  "icon": The name of the icon used to represent the app
}
```

All you need is to make a simple REST request with `HttpClient` or start using `Podio-dotnet` [NUGET package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio/).

```
using PodioAPI;

var podio = new Podio(clientId, clientSecret);
podio.AuthenticateWithApp(appId, appSecret);

var application = await podio.ApplicationService.GetApp(appId, "micro");
```

ItemName can be accessed via `application.ItemName`.

For more information, this is the signature of the method `GetApp`.

```
/// <summary>
///     Gets the definition of an app and can include configuration and fields.
///     <para>Podio API Reference: https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349 </para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="appId"></param>
/// <param name="view">
///     The type of the view of the app requested. Can be either "full", "short", "mini" or "micro". Default
///     value: full
/// </param>
/// <param name="fields">
///     This parameter can be used to include more or less content in responses than the defaults provided by Podio.
///     E.g. space.view(full)
/// </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<Application> GetApp(int appId, string view = "full", string fields = null)
```

If you need to know what other fields `Application` class has, take a look on its [source](https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/blob/50d4b8465c5bcfa8fd450a618b67246b7f293a1a/Source/Podio%20.NET/Models/Application.cs).

Comment: Thank you! I kept looking at the item level instead of application.